# Cannot select div by id in jquery

Tags: jquery

I think this is very simple, but I really can't realize why this code isn't working.

HTML

```
<div class="gallery" id"rieti">
  <div class="gallery_immagini">
    <img class="img_A" src="grafica/nero.gif">
    <img class="img_B" src="grafica/nero.gif">
  </div>
  <script>carica_la_gallery("rieti", 7);</script>
</div>
```

JS

```
function carica_la_gallery (nome_gallery, tot_immagini) {
  alert($("#"+nome_gallery).attr('class'));
}
```

It gives undefined.

After this I have to select the images on its child div and change their sources. Should I use?

```
$("#"+nomegallery).find(".img_A").attr('src', 'where the img is');
```

Is this right?

Comment: What does alert(nome_gallery) gives you? And does this match with the element ID you want to find?

Comment: You forgot an `=` in your `<div>`: `<div class="gallery" id="rieti">`

Comment: Really !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typo ?


Comment: you must be new in HTML too, how couldnt you see this?? :)

Comment: @reyaner - we've all had simple things bother us at some point :) honest mistake. I would give OP benefit of the doubt

Comment: I did a stupid mistake!!! But still, how to select .img_A that is in #nome_gallery's child? I don't want to select all the istances of .img_A but only the one in this div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="gallery" id"rieti">
```

should be

```
<div class="gallery" id="rieti">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid HTML markup :
Replace :

```
<div class="gallery" id"rieti">
```

With :

```
<div class="gallery" id="rieti">
```

You miss a "=" sign between *id* and *rieti*.